# csrf token is not getting updated in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

csrf tocken is not get updated after success function when alerted the same value is alerted

```js
$.ajax({
       url: '<?php echo base_url()?>home/get_checkin',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {value: id},
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) 
         {
         alert($.cookie(csrf_cookie_name));
         $('#csrf').val($.cookie(csrf_cookie_name));
     $.ajax({
               url: '<?php echo base_url()?>home/get_services',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {value: data.checkin[0].check_in_unique_id},
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data1) 
                {
                    alert($.cookie(csrf_cookie_name));
                $('#csrf').val($.cookie(csrf_cookie_name));
                }
               }); 
         }
      });
```

Comment: it can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/38503275/8849056

Comment: no friend its not worked i tried it

Comment: you can also try `$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;` but this is less secure.

Comment: but i need csrf true